# Distribution of stackexchange reputation

Tags: distributions

Should one expect the reputation on stats.stackexchange.com (or any other stackexchange platfor, for that matter) to be similarly distributed to income? That would be a log-normal distribution, I suppose... What do you think?

Comment: Income of what? Income in which country? You can acually check the distribution of rep with http://data.stackexchange.com/ The log normal (which I think does not model income well)  usually appears as a product of independent identically distributed positive random variables, not sure if that is valid for how reputation accumulates.

Comment: Why don't you just test [the data](http://data.stackexchange.com/) rather than asking people to speculate?